# ModelState.AddModelError dosn`t show my error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, addmodelerror

I have an asp.net core MVC project.
I have an action to check if the email given by the user is existing or not?
but it doesn`t show my ModelError message ??
anyone can help?

this is my Action :

```
 [Route("/VerifyEmail")]
        public IActionResult VerifyEmail()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Route("/VerifyEmail")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult VerifyEmail(VerifyEmailViewModel verifyEmail)
        {
           
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(verifyEmail);
            }
            if (!_userService.IsExistEmail(verifyEmail.Email))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", " ایمیل وارد شده معتبر نیست");
                return View(verifyEmail);
            }   
           
            var currentUser = _userService.GetUserByEmail(verifyEmail.Email);
            return View("/Views/Account/SuccessEmail.cshtml", currentUser);
        }
```

and this is my Razore View :

```
@model GameShop.Data.Domain.ViewModels.VerifyEmailViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="/VerifyEmail" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-group" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="ارسال" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml");}
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you have _ViewImports.cshtml under your Views folder?

Comment: If you return to `VerifyEmail`, the error will be rendered in the view successfully. But how do you access the view, can you share some necessary captures?

Comment: I got the answer my friend, Thanks..